# VBA Code to VLookup Multiple Criteria & Remove Duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a VBA code that returns multiple values for a specific input given a set of criteria - How do I need to change the code to make it return multiple values ONLY if they **are not unique to one another**?

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Formula in cell:

```
=SingleCellExtract(Lookup Cell,Lookup Range,Column Index Number," & ")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Vcx.png)

In the above example, there are no duplicate values - However within my data, multiple names appear on the same date and thus I end up with the below. How do I get it to only return one name UNLESS they're unique to one another?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXDIu.png)

Comment: Can you show a little data and explain a little more?   Not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check to the IF to ensure it is not there already:

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue And InStr(Char & xRet, Char & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char) = 0 Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If

        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - len(char))
End Function
```

[image]